# Existence of solution for second order elliptic partial differential equation on a compact set

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let's consider a compact subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ without boundary. For example, a unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
In that case, do we know the existence of solution to a second order elliptic equation:
$$Lu = f \mbox{ on } \Omega,$$
where $f$ is a smooth function.

When I tried to find a such theorem in Evan's PDE book, there is a Theorem for weak solution existence when $\Omega$ is a domain and has a boundary condition(like Dirichlet or Neumann boundary condition). However, I cannot find any result regarding a subset without boundary. I don't need to find an exact solution here, just wanted to know the existence of a solution. Could anyone help this problem?

Comment: What's an example of a compact set without a boundary?

Comment: @aruralreader $S^2$ in $R^3$.

Comment: Yep, makes sense!